# TypeError: bn_js_1.default is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, nestjs

**Hello everone,**
i just implement **bn.js** in class validator DTO. And got some error like this:

TypeError: bn_js_1.default is not a constructor at Object.transformFn

anyone can help me? here's the DTO:

```
import BN from 'bn.js';
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';

export class IWCreateNftCollectionV1ReqDTO {
  @Transform(({ value }) => new BN(value.toString()))
  royalties:BN;
}
```

And the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/bn.js": "^5.1.0",
    "bn.js": "^5.2.0"
}
```

Thanks

**UPDATE**
**Solved** by adding bellow in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't update your question and add answer to it, rather create an answer in designated section, so that others can review and acknowledge it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like bn.js doesn't use default exports. You can either set `esModuleInterop: true` in your `tsconfig`, or you should be able to do `import * as BN from 'bn.js';` if you don't want to modify that setting

Comment: Yeah this is the solution and explanation too, thanks and sorry for very late response haha

Answer (score 0):

Add the setting `esModuleInterop: true` in the tsconfig file worked for me.